# Python - Reading most recently added or modified excel file (or other format)

Tags: python, excel

How to read the excel file in a certain folder that is most recently added or modified? Assuming that the folder has other excel files or PDFs, MS Words, etc.

What if I want to read the most recent word document?

Comment: [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.listdir), [max](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max), [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.stat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to get a list of all files (excluding folders) in your directory.

`files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if not os.path.isdir(f)]`

With this you can then do all sorts of things.

Want to get list PDF files, most recently modified first?

```
recentPDFs = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == '.pdf'] # Checks the file extension is pdf
recentPDFs.sort(key = lambda f: os.path.getmtime(f), reverse = True) # Sorts by time modified
```

How about excel files, least recently created first?

```
recentExc = [f for f in files if f[-5:] == '.xlsx']
recentExc.sort(key = lambda f: os.path.getctime(f))
```

You can see the pattern now.